# Corrupt FAT32 cluster chain after resizing with parted

Tags: parted, fat

I have a 500GB external USB drive formatted with a single FAT32 partition. I wanted a partition that would support normal Linux filesystem permissions, so I shrank the existing partition using parted:

```
$ parted /dev/sda
(parted) resizepart 1 220GB
```

(There was 216GB of data on it). It looked like that worked fine:

```
(parted) print
Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  220GB  220GB  primary  fat32        lba
```

Then I created a new ext4 partition:

```
(parted) mkpart primary ext4 220GB 500GB
(parted) print
Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  220GB  220GB  primary  fat32        lba
 2      220GB   500GB  280GB  primary  ext4         lba
```

Something didn't work right though, because after trying to mount the new partition and getting errors, I checked the drive again in parted and saw this:

```
(parted) print
Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  220GB  220GB  primary  fat32        lba
 2      220GB   500GB  280GB  primary
```

OK, fix that:

```
$ sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sda2
```

The new partition on sda2 seems to be working fine. The old partition can be mounted just fine and I can view the top level folder structure, but attempting to access any of the subfolders with `cd` or `ls` gives an Input/output error and `$ dmesg|tail` shows variations of

```
FAT-fs (sda1): error, fat_get_cluster: invalid cluster chain (i_pos 0)
```

Running `fsck /dev/sda1` gives:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.25.2
fsck.fat 3.0.27 (2014-11-12)
Seek to 500105216512:Invalid argument
```

Can I rescue the data on the FAT32 partition? Was it naive to think that I could just resize to 220GB and not mess up the existing partition?